# Is there any way to get the width of the segments in a UISegmentedControl that is proportional to content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

In the case where the segments in a `UISegmentedControl` are proportional to content `widthForSegmentAtIndex` seems to return 0 when called from  `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Is there anyway to get the actual widths? (I am using autolayout.)

If not is there any way to get the subview that corresponds to a segment? `segmentedControl.subviews[index]` does not work reliably.

If there is no way to do that is there an alternative to UISegmentedControl that can be used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my testing it appears that the width of the segments will always be equal, regardless of the size of the text of each individual segment.

`CGFloat segmentWidth = segmentedControl.frame.size.width / segmentedControl.numberOfSegments;`

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, the above answer does not work if the segmentedControl is using `apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent`. I can't find an easy way to get the width of the segment in that case.

However, you could manually get the text of the segment you're interested in, then calculate how long it 'should' be (depending on how much padding you want on either side), then use that number and use the `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:` method to set the segment to the calculated width, then you would know for sure the width for the segment.

Comment: There's a setting to have the width of the segments be proportional to the contents.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thanks! I missed that, I will look into apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent more

Answer (score 0):

The following category gives NSSegmentedControl the ability to tell you its computed segment widths. It's not perfect- see the disclaimer in comments.

```
@implementation NSSegmentedControl (SegmentedControlWidthComputation)
/* Note: This implementation doesn't properly handle cells with images. It also makes some guesses about AppKit's behavior, and should be treated as an estimation rather than an exact value. */
- (CGFloat)computedWidthForSegment:(NSInteger)SEGIDX
{
    CGFloat pad = 0;
    switch (self.controlSize) {
        case (NSControlSizeMini): pad = 16; break;
        case (NSControlSizeSmall): pad = 22; break;
        case (NSControlSizeRegular): pad = 28; break;
    }

    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self labelForSegment:SEGIDX] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font}].size.width + pad;
}
@end
```